# how to get a slider value on a release tap event in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-mobile, slider, tap

i have a simple slider

```
<input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" min="0" max="100" value="50">
```

i would like to get its value when i release a tap event on it.

something like what the `change` event does in the example below

```
$('#time_slider').on("change", function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
});
```

I'm open to examples outside JQM as well

any ideas?

Comment: Ideally tap events doesn't work with sliders, cause sliders are meant to slide and not tap.

Comment: using 1.4 beta, yes please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it

```
$('#time_slider').on("slidestop", function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
});
```